Using NASM db string from data section in C causes segmentation fault
Minimal reproducible example:
foo.s:
global foo

section .data

foo: db "bar", 0

main.c:
#include <stdio.h>

extern char *foo;

int main() {
    puts(foo);
}

Where I'm running these commands on a 64-bit Ubuntu computer:
nasm -f elf64 foo.s
gcc main.c foo.o
./a.out

But this prints "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
I've tried a mix of -fPIC and -no-pie, but haven't been able to get rid of the runtime segmentation fault with the combinations I've tried.
Running nm foo.o prints 0000000000000000 D foo, which seems correct, as the capitalized D means global data according to nm's man page.
By compiling with -g I can step into main() and run p foo to see that gdb states that foo its address is just wrong:
$1 = 0x726162 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x726162>

Try extern char foo[]; Your foo is not a pointer.

That was it, thank you very much! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it @Jester

...and that's why const char[] = "foo" is more efficient than const char* = "foo".

Addition: The address you observed in the debugger as $1 = 0x726162 happens to be "bar" in little endian (0x62 = "b", 0x61 = "a", 0x72 = "r").
